# Trouble loading scripts in Wordpress child theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, gsap

I am trying to develop my first Wordpress Theme and I'm having trouble loading a couple of javascript files inside my child theme's functions.php file. I must be missing something as my script isn't running but I'm fairly positive my syntax is correct.

Here is the code I have added to my functions.php file in my child theme. It loads a javascript animation library and then my custom script, none of which rely on jQuery.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_scripts');

function custom_theme_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('GSAP','http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js', true);
    wp_register_script('Animations', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/animation.js', true);

    wp_enqueue_script('GSAP');
    wp_enqueue_script('Animations');
}
```

This is my custom script targeting a .svg element on the page with an id of "logo"

```
window.onload = function() {

    var logo = document.getElementById("logo");
    TweenLite.to(logo, 1.5, { width:5000 });

};
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Or is it just that nothing is happening?

Comment: Nothing is happening at all. No errors in the JavaScript console either.

Comment: I just added window.onload and still nothing is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code in one of my child themes, including your javascript code and all runs with no problem.

Be sure when you create child themes for your own WordPress themes that you make the correct setup:

1. style.css: Check it contains the correct header, which basically includes the tilte line with the directory name of the parent theme.
2. functions.php: When you include your child theme you have to add the registration of the parent style.css in the functions.php of the child theme. In other words, before activating your child theme, be sure you include this when you register scripts:

.

```
wp_register_style( 'childstyle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'  );
wp_enqueue_style( 'childstyle' );
```

Beside that if everything is setup properly it should load your scripts. Check the resources that have been loaded through the development tools you have in your browser. Or try to load any other javascript line to check the script is running.

That script you posted works if the rest of the theme setup has been done properly. I cannot tell more than that, I hope it helps

Comment: That's what I'm confused about, I followed the codex exactly and I know my child theme is set up correctly because if I make adjustments in my child's style it shows up in my theme and the parents default style shows up so that's still being loaded. I'm using the underscores template but I really don't think that has any blame.

Comment: So now I notice that my scripts aren't even showing up in the source code so they're not even making it past the enqueue part

Comment: And no errors either right? Hard to picture it since your code looks right. I copied it straight and it worked to me. Can you provide any link to see it? And maybe a link to a file with the raw content of your functions.php. It might be something completely different. But it is hard to know so far.